# Why does SOS update a file to a previous revision?

Tags: version-control, repository

This question is about the SOS version control system:

I have a file that always updates back to revision 1.  For instance, to check out the latest revision I have to specifically ask for that revision.  I have checked in several revisions up to revision 5.  However, everytime I do an SOS update, it reloads revision 1.

How can I request that the file updates to the latest revision rather than an older one?

Comment: Just a guess, but is the file part of a composite object?

Comment: Not sure what that means, but I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked with a tech support rep on the phone and this is what we found out:

I was working with a file in repo *A*.
The file in question had a tag, *tag_x* on revision 1.  Furthermore, the file was included as a "reference" file from another repository, repo *B*.  In the revision search order (RSO) for repo *A*, it was set to load files tagged with *tag_x* before the main revision when they were referenced from repo *B*, which is why it kept updating to revision 1 instead of the latest revision.

Pretty complicated, but found out the problem and was able to fix temporarily by updating the tag, though a permanent fix would be to remove the line from the RSO.